# Typescript: type that has all the base attributes and allows any extensions

Tags: typescript, types, extend

Let's suppose I have an interface that describes only fields I'm interested in:

```js
interface RestResponse {
    data: {
        name: string;
        value: number;
    }
    status: number;
}
```

I would like to use this interface as a type for a real REST response that has more fields than these above. E.g.:

```js
const sampleResponse = {
    data: {
        name: 'cat',
        value: 64,
        description: 'the field I won't use anywhere'
    }
    status: 200,
    isSuccessful: true
}
```

The question is what type `sampleResponse` should be?
I cannot make it:

```js
const sampleResponse: RestResponse = { ... }
```

because the type doesn't have fields like `isSuccessful` and `data.description`.

It's an extension of `RestResponse`. I expect it to have all the fields specified in the interface, but don't mind having any additional ones.

---

So far I tried looking at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html, but can't find anything useful for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an indexer, which allows any key which any value

That would look like this:

```js
interface RestResponse {
  data: { 
    name: string;
    value: number;
  } 
  status: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

#### What is a type indexer?

`[key: string]: any` is an object indexer.

`[key: string]` specifies that you can add any key to the object that is of type `string`

The `: any` after the indexer defines that the value of the key should be `any` and since `any` allows anything - you can add anything

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't though of that!

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the problem, you can click the checkmark ✅ to accept my question - Also please avoid "thank you" comments. It's nice of you but you should prefer the built in quality control methods like votes.